# Powershell command fails with "Invalid namespace" only when running as script, not in console

Tags: powershell

The following script fails on the last line with `Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace`:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $password )
Write-Host "Entering PS Session..."
Enter-PSSession -Computer hyperVServer -Credential $cred
Start-Sleep -s 5
$server = "servername"

$query = "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='" + $server + "'"
$VM = get-wmiobject -query $query -namespace "root\virtualization" -computername "."
```

However, when I enter this one-by-one into the console, it runs without issue.

I've added the `Start-Sleep` due to some timing issues... the session takes a few seconds to actually open. Any ideas why that line would fail only when this is running as a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter-PSSession is intended only for interactive use. If you want to run commands on a remote system in a script (non-interactively), you'll need to use Invoke-Command instead. Please run Get-Help Invoke-Command -Full for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works in one and not the other, but I assuming it's something to do with your remote session. Here's a list of commands that do not require a remote session, but rather just take a computer name. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $password )
$server = "servername"
$query = "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName=$server"
$VM = get-wmiobject -query $query -namespace "root\virtualization" -computername hyperVServer -credential $cred
```

Edited your query concat too.